# pdf download in PHP using FPDF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I am trying to generate one pdf in php code using fpdf. This is my ajax call

```
form = $('#caw_auto_form');
validator = form.validate();
data = form.serializeObject();
valid = validator.form();
//alert("here");
ajax('pos/pos_api.php',data,function(response){
    //alert("result");
    alert(response);



});
```

and in my back end

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
echo $pdf->output();
```

in the give function. I but it is not generating pdf and downloading automatically. Am I missing some basic things. And I am not familiar with php codes.

Comment: @CliffBurton this is a template. My doubt instead of alerting shoud i do something else. I am getting response.

Comment: I dont think the template has a role in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To force PDF download you should redirect the page to `pos/pos_api.php` and inside `pos/pos_api.php` before `echo $pdf->output();` send headers

```
$pdf = $pdf->output('/tmp/tmp_file.pdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize ( '/tmp/tmp_file.pdf' ));
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="some_pdf_to_download.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: public'); 
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
readfile('/tmp/tmp_file.pdf');
```

Comment: Thaks a lot plamen. Let  me try this. before that kindly chek my js code also..instead of alert shoud i use something else??

Comment: I have tried this code. Now the response is null.should i add anything else for this header and all.

Comment: make sure that the pdf file is saved correctly in the /tmp folder.

Comment: can you please explain what is this '/tmp/tmp_file.pdf' . In case of me "C:\Users\anandh\Downloads" this is fine?

Comment: on Windows .. the tmp folder is on different place .. try to use  sys_get_temp_dir()

for example `$pdf_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf');` and than `$pdf->output($pdf_file);`